# GWT Canvas pixel manipulation is dreadfully slow

Tags: gwt, html5-canvas

Execution time to build a canvas pixel-by-pixel in GWT is extremely slow.  For the following code, the 2D for loop with calls to "cpa.set(...)" is very slow.

```
...
RootPanel.get().add(canvas);
context = canvas.getContext2d();
ImageData id = context.createImageData(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
CanvasPixelArray cpa = id.getData();

for (int y=0; y<canvasHeight; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<canvasWidth; x++){
        cpa.set(y*canvasWidth*4 + x*4 + 0,r);
        cpa.set(y*canvasWidth*4 + x*4 + 1,g);
        cpa.set(y*canvasWidth*4 + x*4 + 2,b);
        cpa.set(y*canvasWidth*4 + x*4 + 3,a);
    }
}           
context.putImageData(id, 0, 0);
```

For example, with a 100x100 canvas, it takes 10 seconds.  I've seen in some other javascript posts [here](http://www.onaluf.org/en/entry/13) showing that it may be more efficient to use a separate array buffer in the for loop, then just set the ImageData array equal to that buffer, but GWT doesn't seem to allow that with CanvasPixelArray, you can only set a single pixel at a time in GWT, rather than copy an entire pixel array buffer into a CanvasPixelArray or ImageData.

Any ideas for efficient pixel manipulation with GWT canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: The GWT canvas related stuff is dead simple (CanvasPixelArray is just an overlay type with nothing in it). Should be just as fast as doing this in vanilla JS. Have you tried same code in vanilla JS to compare perfomance?

Comment: Yes, when I replace the pixel manipulating looping code with JS (using GWT's JSNI as described [here](http://www.onaluf.org/en/entry/13)) it loads the page instantly. (Since the Java version is so terribly slow, I'm not using any accurate method to compare performance.  GWT Java is ~10seconds,  GWT JSNI is instant)

Comment: Are you running a compiled version? That is to say, you're not running in DevMode? DevMode can be notoriously slow for things like this.

Comment: @aez: From experience I can tell you that Canvas in dev mode is a magnitude slower than in production mode (compiled). So if you want to check performance, then check it in production mode.

Comment: @Umit and Danny Kirchmeir:  you are correct, when I deploy to app engine, the page loads instantly!  It is almost unusable in development mode, is there anyway around this?  Can the compiled version somehow be used in dev mode, or is that impossible by definition?  Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Chrome for development mode, ironically it has several outstanding issues that prevent the DevMode plug-in from running fast. Try developing in Firefox and see if it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have diagnosed your problem as *Running in Devmode*, I'll detail some solutions here.

First off, like Strelock commented, DevMode in Firefox is a good deal faster. Personally, I do all of my development in Firefox.

Still, it sounds like Devmode will be unmanagable for you while developing/testing this. Your only option here is to compile. Thankfully, there are some parameters that we can tweak to speed it up, reducing it down to the 20 to 40 second mark assuming you have a project of decent size.

Given a main **com/foobar/MyApplication.gwt.xml** file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="myapplication">
   ...
</module>
```

Lets create another, **com/foobar/MyApplication-Firefox.gwt.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='myapplication'>
   <inherits name='com.foobar.MyApplication'/>
   <!-- If you want to compile for a different browser, substitute this value. -->
   <set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8"/>
</module>
```

Now when we compile, make sure to use the `-draftCompile` parameter. The compiled version may be a little less efficient, but it'll compile down faster. If you are using the default **build.xml** file, you can add another target like so:

```
<target name="gwtc-firefox" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (for FireFox)">
  <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="src"/>
      <path refid="project.class.path"/>
      <pathelement location="${gwt.path}/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />
      <pathelement location="${gwt.path}/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
     </classpath>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
    <arg line="-war"/>
    <arg value="war"/>
    <arg line="-draftCompile"/>
    <arg value="com.foobar.MyApplication-Firefox"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out.  I was called for Jury Duty today (civic duty in the US) so I'll try it as soon as I am dismissed.

Comment: ok, all works good.  As it turns out, Firefox is faster in dev mode, and Chrome is blazing fast in production mode, at least for this canvas pixel manipulation problem.